# Good step by step tutorial on setting up sass in sublime text 2

Tags: sass, sublimetext2

Is there a good tutorial on setting up SASS for Sublime Text 2 on Windows? I've been looking and I have not come up with anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Sass build plugin (available [here](https://github.com/jaumefontal/SASS-Build-SublimeText2)), and if you want to do it yourself, you can just read how the plugin do it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer mate, I used scout instead

Comment: You're welcome. In my project (involving Jekyll or Hyde in general), I use a makefile with, among other things, this line : "sass --update sass/:media/css/". With that makefile, I use the Ctrl+B shortcut to build my sass, site and all.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Scout](http://mhs.github.com/scout-app/) to get up and running. This program is really good and also offers compression.